# Web API Testing - Postman with JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am new to Web API and trying learn how to debug Web API with POSTMAN.It is working with GET request only POST request has some trouble. I am not able to trouble shoot what exactly the error is.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage StudentDetails(Student data)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(data).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

And Student Class is  as below.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string PersonalEmail { get; set; }
}
```

And I am trying to test the above action in POSTMAN. I added Content-Type as "application-json" and passing JSON as below .

```
{
  StudentId :1
   FirstName : 'SINI'   ,
   LastName :'A',
   SSN : '7894300',
   PersonalEmail: 'sini@gmail.com'
}
```

And In the POSTMAN, I gave the below URL :

```
http://localhost:60893/WebAPIDemo/api/Student
```

But it is giving me "The resource cannot be found".

Everything was perfect. I had two projects, one is web API and the other one is MVC. I forgot to keep web API as start up project.

Answer (score 0):

url is not correct, change it to:

> http://localhost:60893/WebAPIDemo/api/StudentDetails